# Run cmd or exe file from asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have problem with running cmd or exe file from asp.net page.

I used this code:

```
protected void btnRun_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var p = new Process();
  var info = new ProcessStartInfo
                            {
                              FileName = Server.MapPath("~/print.cmd"),
                              UseShellExecute = false,
                              WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                            };
  p.StartInfo = info;
  p.Start();
  p.WaitForExit();
}
```

When I run my web application on VS Development Server everything is ok,
but when I deploy this code on IIS (ver 7.5), the code working without errors but 
nothing happens.

- I used search on google and SO, but I didn't find any solution
- I tried http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555134 and http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;317012
- I set 'Allow service to interact with desctop' for IIS Admin service.
- I played with user rights but this didn't give me any results.
- I changed Identity for Application Pools

is it possible to run cmd or exe with IIS?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo
                        {
                          FileName = Server.MapPath("~/print.cmd"),
                          UseShellExecute = true,
                          Verb = "runas",
                          WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                        };
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help me